# Cast dynamic dapper query

Tags: c#, dapper

Im trying to convert a dynamic query from dapper to IDictionary

```
        const string sql = @"SELECT Name, Street FROM Contact";
        dynamic query = null;

        using (var cn = Connection)
        {
            query = cn.Query<dynamic>(sql);
        }

        var rows = query as IDictionary<string, object>;

        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            // Getting values and objects
        }
```

But the cast always return null. Any clue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to cast the individual rows as `IDictionary<string, object>`:

```
    const string sql = @"SELECT Name, Street FROM Contact";
    IEnumerable<dynamic> results = null;

    using (var cn = Connection)
    {
        results = cn.Query<dynamic>(sql);
    }

    foreach (var row in results)
    {
         var fields = row as IDictionary<string, object>;
         // do something with fields["Name"] and fields["Street"]
    }
```

Comment: You can simplify to `foreach(IDictionary<string, object> row in ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Use "Cast<>":

```
query.Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>()
```